# Access to moderator tools privilege wiki might need another update?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, privileges

At the bottom of the information page for [access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), you see this:

> ### More!
>
> This privilege also grants you access to the following lists:
>
> - recently closed questions
> - recently imported questions
> - new answers to old questions
> - suggested edit stats
> - anonymous feedback stats
>
> These help highlight potential problem areas – or just areas of high activity – on the site.

I was just a bit confused about the `new answers to old questions` bullet item. Would this not be the same thing as the `late answers` tab now available in the review section? If not, what's the difference?

Somewhat related, I also thought I read somewhere that the moderation tools were no longer at `/tools` and were merged into `/review` with everything else, but the link on that page still points to `/tools/flagged`?

I don't want to edit things when I'm not 100% sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also thought I read somewhere that the moderation tools were no longer at /tools and were merged into /review with everything else, but the link on that page still points to /tools/flagged?

No, these still remain. The review page displays a subset of tools available at `/tools`

> If not, what's the difference?

The difference is that New Answers to Old Questions shows new answers by **anyone** to questions older than 30 days, while Late Answers shows list of answers to old questions provided by **users with less than 10 reputation** - with the added option of show answers posted last day/weeek/month/year/since start.